# Puppet: how to add a line to an existing file

Tags: puppet

I am trying to add a line to an existing file /etc/fuse.conf. I tried this

added a folder two folders under modules directory

```
sudo mkdir /etc/puppet/modules/test
sudo mkdir /etc/puppet/modules/test/manifests
```

Then created a test.pp file and added following lines

```
sudo vim /etc/puppet/modules/test/manifests/test.pp

file { '/etc/fuse.conf':
  ensure => present,
}->
file_line { 'Append a line to /etc/fuse.conf':
  path => '/etc/fuse.conf',
  line => 'Want to add this line as a test',
}
```

After that I ran this command

```
puppet apply /etc/puppet/modules/test/manifests/test.pp
```

Then I opened this file `/etc/fuse.conf` and there was no change in the file. The line was not added to the file. I don't understand what I am missing here. How can I do this? I am learning puppet. So this is only for learning purpose.

Comment: Did the `puppet apply ....` command produce any output? Could you include it in your question? Thanks!

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36045455/781723, http://serverfault.com/q/764220/111679, http://superuser.com/q/1053789/93541.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which version of puppet you are using, since you didn't mention it.
The "file_name" class belongs to the puppetlabs-stdlib library, so you need to make sure that this module is installed -

```
puppet module install puppetlabs-stdlib
```

also, since you are using a module path, you need to call your file init.pp (not test.pp).
Since you are new to writing modules, I suggest you use the puppet module generate command -

```
puppet module generate module-name --skip-interview
```

this will create all you'll need for a new module.
don't forget to make sure that the class name is the same as the module's name.
In order to run and test this module, use -

```
puppet apply  -e "include <module-name>"
```